# Webservice methods using EclipseLink and database entities

Tags: java, synchronization, web-services

I am wondering if this is a good and correct way to write the implementation of two web service methods (get/set methods).

The `setPerson` method can be called from different threads from a pool, so I think the best way is to make the method `synchronized`. Or is it possible to lock the table when editing to avoid the synchronization on Java?

```
@Override
public synchronized void setPerson(Person person) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersonLibPU");            
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(); 
    if(!em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
       em.getTransaction().begin();
    }
    try {
         em.merge(person);
         em.getTransaction().commit();  
         emf.getCache().evict(Person.class);                    
    } catch (Exception ex) {
         if(em.getTransaction().isActive())
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

And here follows the `getPerson` method. I didn't make it `synchronized` since it reads from the JPA cache.

```
@Override
public Person getPerson(int personId) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersonLibPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    try {           
        return (Person)em.getReference(Person.class, personId);
    } catch (javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException ex) {
        return new Person(); // return empty person
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a few notes:

```
if(!em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
   em.getTransaction().begin();
}
try {
     em.merge(person);
     em.getTransaction().commit();  
     emf.getCache().evict(Person.class);
} catch (Exception ex) {
     if(em.getTransaction().isActive())
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
} finally {
    em.close();
}
```

I'd create a local variable for `em.getTransaction()` here and move the `isActive` check inside the `try` block.

```
try {
    EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
    try {
        if (!transaction.isActive()) {
            transaction.begin();
        }
        em.merge(person);
        transaction.commit();  
        emf.getCache().evict(Person.class);
    } finally {
        if (transaction.isActive()) {
            em.transaction.rollback();
        }
    }
} finally {
    em.close();
}
```

It closes the `EntityManager` in every code path as well as the transaction.

I've removed the exception catching. If you catch it consider at least logging it.

Evicting the whole `Person` cache every time you save a `Person` entity does not seem a good idea for performance.

Please note that if something call this method with an active transaction (I'm not sure if it's possible at all) it will returns with a committed or rollbacked, but *not* active transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! How about the `synchronize` issue? Can I remove it if I use `em.lock(person, WRITE);` instead? Will any other transaction way for the lock to be released?

Comment: @Rox: To be honest, the `synchronize` smells for me, but I'm afraid I'm not so familiar with EclipseLink to answer this question. I guess there is a better solution than that. This part of your question may fit better on StackOverflow.